# Cayley's Theorem - Trying to prove via bijective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

"Since the operation of left multiplication is faithful, $G$ is isomorphic to its image in $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$. If $G$ has order $n$, $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ is isomorphic to $S_n$." - Artin's Algebra

So left multiplication as an action means $\phi_g(x)=gx$

So proving isomorphism, means bijective homomorphism, but I don't understand:

Injective: $ga_1=b$ and $ga_2=b$ $\implies a_1=g^{-1}b=a_2,\square$

Surjective: $\forall b\in G, ga=b$ where you can let $a=g^{-1}b$ where clearly $g^{-1}b\in G$ whenever $g,b\in G$. $\square$

But then homomorphism fails since $\phi_g(ab)=gab\ne\phi_g(a)\phi_g(b)=gagb$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing $G$ as a group and $G$ as left-acting on itself. The homomorphism is this:
\begin{align*}
\varphi\colon G&\to \operatorname{Perm}G\\
g&\mapsto (\varphi_g\colon a\mapsto ga)
\end{align*}

It is a homomorphism because $\;\varphi_{gg'}\colon a\mapsto(gg')a=g(g'a)=\varphi_g\bigl(\varphi_{g'}(a)\bigr)$, hence $\;\varphi_{gg'}=\varphi_g\circ\varphi_{g'}$.

It is injective because  $\;\varphi_g=\operatorname{id}_G\;$ means that, if $ga=a$ for all $a\in G$ (actually one $a$ is enough), then $g=e$.

Comment: Where $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$  is another notation for $\operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{Set}}(G)$ or $\operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(G)$ or neither if you know?

Comment: It denotes permutations of $G$ as a set.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(g)$ is bijective as you said, so it belongs to $Perm(G) \cong S_{n}$. Now the map, used in Cayley's theorem, is $f:G \to Perm(G)$, $f(g) =\phi_{g}$. $\phi$ is not necessarly a homomorphism, but $f$ is a homomorphism, in fact injective. Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: You mean $\phi_g\subset \operatorname{Perm}(G)$ in the first line?

Where does $f$ come from? I don't really get how a function of functions works, i.e. $f$ is a function that 'equips' the group action with $g\in G$?

Comment: For example, consider the identity $e$ of $G$. $\phi_{e}(x)=ex=x$, so you're sending $g \in G$ to the function that multiplies everything on the lefft by $g$.